# webpack 4 sass-loader not resolving global SCSS variables

Tags: sass, babeljs, webpack-4, node-sass, sass-loader

I've been trying to get SCSS global variables to work using webpack, but it doesn't seem to resolve the paths correctly in any attempt I make.

The config looks as following (using electron-webpack, extending the default config)

```
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const webpackRenderer = require('electron-webpack/webpack.renderer.config.js');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const { extend, find, flow, has } = require('lodash');

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

function replaceLoader(config, test, callback) {
  const rule = find(config.module.rules, (r) => String(r.test) === String(test));

  if (rule) {
    extend(rule, callback(rule));
  }

  return config;
}

// Since we want to uses SCSS modules, we need to replace the
// default SCSS loader config that ships with electron-webpack.
function replaceSassLoader(config) {
  const minimize = isProd
    ? [
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            plugins: [cssnano({ preset: 'default' })]
          }
        }
      ]
    : [];

  return replaceLoader(config, /\.scss$/, () => ({
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: {
            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
          },
          sourceMap: !isProd,
          importLoaders: 1
        }
      },
      ...minimize,
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
          data:
            '@import "~common/stylesheets/variables"; @import "~common/stylesheets/mixins"; @import "~common/stylesheets/themes";',
          includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'src/common')],
          sourceMap: !isProd
        }
      }
    ]
  }));
}

module.exports = async (env) => {
  const config = await webpackRenderer(env);

  const newConfig = merge.smart(config, {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        common: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'src/common'),
      }
    }
  });

  return flow(replaceSassLoader)(newConfig);
};
```

Used versions:

```
    "electron-webpack": "2.7.4",
    "node-sass": "4.13.0",
    "sass-loader": "8.0.0",
    "webpack": "4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.9.0",
    "webpack-merge": "4.2.2"
```

Whatever attempt/tweaks I do to the path resolving/config I continue to receive the same errors like these:

```
[start:renderer]  @ multi css-hot-loader/hotModuleReplacement ./src/renderer/index.js
[start:renderer] Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
[start:renderer]      1 asset
[start:renderer]     Entrypoint undefined = index.html
[start:renderer]     [./node_modules/html-loader/dist/cjs.js?minimize=false&url=false!./dist/.renderer-index-template.html] 360 bytes {0} [built]
[start:renderer] Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-2!node_modules/rc-tooltip/assets/bootstrap.css:
[start:renderer]     Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
[start:renderer]     [./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/rc-tooltip/assets/bootstrap.css] ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-2!./node_modules/rc-tooltip/assets/bootstrap.css 4.22 KiB {mini-css-extract-plugin} [built]
[start:renderer]     [./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js] 2.61 KiB {mini-css-extract-plugin} [built]
[start:renderer] Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-2!node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!src/renderer/account/components/Account/Account.scss:
[start:renderer]     Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
[start:renderer]     [./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/renderer/account/components/Account/Account.scss] ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/renderer/account/components/Account/Account.scss 368 bytes {mini-css-extract-plugin} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[start:renderer]     
[start:renderer]     ERROR in ./src/renderer/account/components/Account/Account.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/renderer/account/components/Account/Account.scss)
[start:renderer]     Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
[start:renderer]     SassError: Undefined variable: "$responsive-width".
[start:renderer]             on line 18 of /<path_to_project>/src/renderer/account/components/Account/Account.scss
[start:renderer]     >>     @media only screen and (max-width: $responsive-width) {
[start:renderer]     
[start:renderer]        ---------------------------------------^


[start:renderer] Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-2!node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!src/renderer/shared/components/Panel/Panel.scss:
[start:renderer]     Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
[start:renderer]     [./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/renderer/shared/components/Panel/Panel.scss] ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/renderer/shared/components/Panel/Panel.scss 432 bytes {mini-css-extract-plugin} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[start:renderer] 
[start:renderer]     ERROR in ./src/renderer/shared/components/Panel/Panel.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/renderer/shared/components/Panel/Panel.scss)      
[start:renderer]     Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
[start:renderer]     SassError: ".panel" failed to @extend "%panelColor".
[start:renderer]            The selector "%panelColor" was not found.
[start:renderer]            Use "@extend %panelColor !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.
[start:renderer]             on line 2 of D:\Development\<path>\src\renderer\shared\components\Panel\Panel.scss
[start:renderer]     >>   @extend %panelColor;
[start:renderer]        ----------^
```

It all used to be working with webpack 2/babel 6.
We used module resolving from babel 6, which was removed in babel 7, so I replaced it with the webpack 4 resolution aliases and that was the point where all the above issues arised when upgrading all the webpack/babel related packages

Comment: Please post the code of SCSS file.